# Definition of multivariate martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I cannot find a proper definition of multivariate martingale. If each component is $1$-dimensional martingale is it enough for a $d$-dimensional process to be a martingale?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the parameter set is still one-dimensional, and the values are in a vector space like $\mathbb R^n$?  Then yes, the definition can be that each component is individually a martingale.  Or abstractly that when we apply any linear functional, the result is a scalar-valued martingale.

"Multivariate martingale" might also mean a situation where "time" is replaced by a multi-dimensional parameter set.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about one-dimensional time. Thanks. Just out of curiosity where I read about multi-dimensional parameter set?

Comment: The theory of martingales indexed by $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ was initiated in a memoir of Cairoli & Walsh (1975).  A 1981 book of Korezliogly, Mazziotto & Szpirglas is a collection of articles on this topic.  There is a general notion "block martingale" due to Frangos & Sucheston (1985), and work of Sucheston & Szabo (1991).  The last chapter of Edgar & Sucheston http://www.math.osu.edu/~edgar/books/stdp.html has lots of this.